# Calling HttpHandler from an area

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, httphandler, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have a simple asp.net mvc 4 website with an admin area. I have defined a custom http handler to handle uploads from a plupload script that runs in the admin area. Here is the code for the handler :

`public class CategoryImageUploadHandler : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
    {`

```
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpPostedFile file = context.Request.Files[0];

            var categoryID = context.Request["categoryID"];
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            var parentPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Files/Content");
            var targetDir =  Path.Combine(parentPath, categoryID);
            var targetFile = Path.Combine(targetDir, fileName);
            //check if Directory exists
            if (Directory.Exists(targetDir))
                file.SaveAs(targetFile);
            else
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(targetDir);
                file.SaveAs(targetFile);
            }
            context.Response.Write("/"+categoryID+"/"+fileName);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            context.Response.Write("0");
            context.Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
}
```

This is sitting in the Handlers/ directory of the main site. This is how I have registered the handler :

```
 <system.webserver>
       <add name="CategoryImageUploadHandler path="Admin/CategoryImageUploadHandler.ashx" verb="*" type="Hitaishi.Web.Handlers.CategoryImageUploadHandler, Hitaishi.Web"/>

 <system.web>
      <httpHandlers>
           <add path="Admin/CategoryImageUploadHandler.ashx" verb="*" type="Hitaishi.Web.Handlers.CategoryImageUploadHandler, Hitaishi.Web"/>

  Routeconfig.cs:
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{*allashx}", new { allashx = @".*\.ashx(/.*)?" });
```

However, when the plupload sends a POST to the http handler from the Admin area, the call is still picked up by routing as it tries to look for

```
/Admin/CategoryImageUploadHandler.ashx
```

I have tried playing with slashes to check if the path I am giving is wrong or changing path in the registrations, but nothing seems to work. I am still getting 404 errors.

In a nutshell, I need a way to reference a HttpHandler defined in the main MVC area of the website from another mvc area of the website. Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

why are you not using `routes.MapPageRoute`
so probably you can do

```
routes.MapPageRoute(
"CategoryImageUploaded", 
"Admin/CategoryImageUploadHandler.ashx", 
"~/Admin/CategoryImageUploadHandler.ashx")

    //please verify you path to .ashx before trying
```